# Should I use a colon or semicolon in a list that doesn't end with "and"?

Tags: lists, semicolons, colons

Should I use colon or semicolon in the following?

> I liked the atmosphere: the rusty tables, the old wooden walls, the
>    Western-style counter.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a colon after "atmosphere" and commas after "tables" and "walls." A colon precedes a list; a semicolon is a list separator. A semicolon is most often used to separate clauses in a sentence which are not separated by a conjunction (such as "and" or "or.") I illustrated correct use of a semicolon in the second sentence of this answer.